# memory leak in sqlite

Tags: memory, memory-leaks

Every time I connect to sqlite an object create and remain, here is code that for connect to db

```
+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath :(NSString *)searchtext{

    MashahirAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MashahirAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSString *cat=[[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",@"-",[MashahirAppDelegate catid],@"-"]autorelease];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *query=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"select ID, Name from Profile where name like '%@%@%@%@%@",@"%",searchtext,@"%' and ParentCat like '%",cat,@"%' order by name"];


        const char *sql = [query UTF8String ];

        [query release];
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                MashahirDB *MashahirDBObj = [[MashahirDB alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                MashahirDBObj.Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

                [appDelegate.MashahirArray addObject:MashahirDBObj];
                [MashahirDBObj release];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
    }

        sqlite3_close(database); 
}
```

this is a picture from instrument:
[Picture from Instrument http://029.img98.net/out.php/i282779_12121.png](http://029.img98.net/out.php/i282779_12121.png)

Comment: @user731189: Welcome to SO. If you're interested in getting better answers & help from the community you can help yourself out by clearly defining your problem & asking clear & concise questions for people to help you solve. "This is not working" & a code block usually are difficult to debug, and likely will be more difficult for you to get help for.

Answer (score 0):

The picture you have linked doesn't show any memory leaks, it is the allocations detail and it is normal for you to see those allocations.

Comment: yes but every time connect to db 1 object add to Malloc 51.00k and overall byte increase

Comment: @DreaomOfMirrors: Welcome to SO, Thank you for showing your interest in helping with this question. Typically when we respond to a person's question with something that isn't an answer we leave comments on the question. Answers are usually reserved for solutions to the original question.

Comment: @Aren: Thank you for your advice, I think I cannot post any comments if not in response to other comments. Maybe I was wrong, sorry.